# Converting JSON list to dictionary

Tags: python

I am using `python` and have the following JSON block, `json_player`, which is stored as a list:

```
[
    {
        "id": "name",
        "value": "john"
    },
    {
        "id": "sport",
        "value": "baseball"
    },
    {
        "id": "age",
        "value": "20"
    }
]
```

Note that this is the resulting block from:

```
json_object = json.loads(df['customFields'])
json_player = json_object['player']
```

I know that I can access individual strings within `json_player` using the following code:

```
json_player[0]['value']
```

Which would return the string `john`.

However, I would like to be able to call individual key-value pairs by name, rather than index, in order to protect myself if underlying JSON order changes. For example:

```
json_player['name']
```

would return `john`. Can anyone tell me how I would do this?

Comment: things could be clearer if the list was assigned to a variable and where did df['customFields'] come from. the data frame might have a query mechanism, or you could craft a map-reduce scheme.  Also, this is the kind of stuff that an orm and sqlite is good for.

Comment: There is no such thing, from Python, as "a JSON list". Once you have parsed the data, you have a *perfectly ordinary* data structure made of *perfectly ordinary* lists and dicts, which you work with *the exact same way* as if you had gotten *the same data, by any other means*. Therefore, it is not a question about JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily construct the dictionary using a [dict comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/):

```
data = {
    item["id"]: item["value"]
    for item in json_player
}
print(data)
# => {'name': 'john', 'sport': 'baseball', 'age': '20'}
```